# Proving that $\int_{-b}^{b}f(x)dx=0 $ if $f$ is an odd function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

So I split this integral up into two:

$$ \int_{-b}^{0}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{b}f(x)dx= \int_{-b}^{b}f(x)dx$$

Then I can do the following:

$$ \int_{-b}^{0}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{b}f(x)dx= \int_{0}^{b}f(-x)dx+\int_{0}^{b}f(x)dx$$
and since $f$ is odd $(f(-x)=-f(x))$ we get

$$\int_{0}^{b}-f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{b}f(x)dx=0$$

I'm not really understanding why my second is correct other than if I use substitution, i.e. $x=-y$.

Comment: Substitution is the only way, algebraically, to show that $\int_{-b}^0 f(x) dx = \int_0^b f(-x)dx$. But if you draw a picture it should be intuitively clear as well. It's exactly the same area, just mirrored over the $y$-axis. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: Ah okay, thought so. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach. Let's assume $f$ is sufficiently regular on a given set. By the [fondamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) and the chain rule, we get that
$$
\left(\int_{-b}^{b}f(x)dx\right)'=f(b)-(-f(-b))=0
$$ giving that
$$
\int_{-b}^{b}f(x)\:dx=\text{constant}
$$ by putting $b:=0$, the constant is seen to be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your substitution works without the need to slip the integral.

You have
\begin{align*}
\int _{-b}^b f(x){\rm d}x &= \int _{b}^{-b}-f(-u) {\rm d} u,\,x=-u\\
&=\int _{b}^{-b}f(u) {\rm d} u \\
&=-\int _{-b}^{b}f(u) {\rm d} u\\
&=-\int _{-b}^b f(x){\rm d}x
\end{align*}
Therefore $\int _{-b}^b f(x){\rm d}x =0$.

So the algebraic idea was since we know $f(-x)=-f(x)$, make the substitution $u=-x$ and see that it can be derived.

Comment: "split", not "slip".

Comment: @AlexM. oops I slipped